# What is the error in my code

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I have a layout in which there are 4 `Button`, the `Button` are placed in a separate `LinearLayout`. The `LinearLayout` have id's assigned to them. Now in my activity which holds this layout, I am creating `LinearLayout` variables and assigning id's to them.

Now when I try to run the code, the following error is displayed .![enter image description here][1]

```
10-19 12:36:43.899: E/AndroidRuntime(21774): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-19 12:36:43.899: E/AndroidRuntime(21774): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.code.accountmanager/com.code.accountmanager.AccountManagerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

also

```
10-19 12:36:43.899: E/AndroidRuntime(21774): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-19 12:36:43.899: E/AndroidRuntime(21774):    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1825)
10-19 12:36:43.899: E/AndroidRuntime(21774):    at com.code.accountmanager.AccountManagerActivity.<init>(AccountManagerActivity.java:22)
```

Also the line in which error is displayed is as:

```
LinearLayout l4 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.anim_recent_transaction);
LinearLayout l3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.anim_view_account);
LinearLayout l2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.anim_add_transaction);
LinearLayout l1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.anim_add_account);
```

here is the xml code

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonHolder"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/anim_add_account"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/addAccount"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/addaccount_new"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/anim_add_transaction"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/addTransaction"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/addtransaction_new"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/anim_view_account"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/viewAccount"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/viewaccounts_new"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/anim_recent_transaction"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/recentTransaction"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/viewtransaction_new"
                android:gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please tell me what could I do to remove the error.

Comment: share complete onCreate() method

Comment: I'm not saying that it is the solution in this case, but sometimes you have to clean and rebuild the project. But please, post layout and more code. Mark line 22.

Comment: The lines you've shown are before setContentView()?

Comment: please share some more code...

Comment: You are getting `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException` error. so try to check your code by debuging and check where you are getting null object. Probably this type of error will come when the requested widget with id is not available in your layout.

Comment: Okay I'm sharing the xml code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `setContentView(R.layout.yourLayoutXML)` before using `findViewById`.
I think that might be your problem

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to identify your error if u had give  a full code of your layout xml files .

in my perspective best way to identify this kind of error is DEBUG your code .

here is the link from where you can get to know about best way to debug   .

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html

Good luck !!